# You can abbreviate list names? Why?

Tags: r, list, names

This got me pretty bad.  You can abbreviate list names?  I never noticed it before and I got totally screwed for like a day.  Can someone explain what is happening here and why it could be more useful than it is terrible?  And why its inconsistent like that at the bottom?  And if I can turn it off?

```
> wtf <- list(whatisthe=1, pointofthis=2)  
> wtf$whatisthe  
[1] 1  
> wtf$what  
[1] 1  

> wtf <- list(whatisthe=1, whatisthepointofthis=2)  
> wtf$whatisthepointofthis  
[1] 2  
> wtf$whatisthep  
[1] 2  
> wtf$whatisthe  
[1] 1  
> wtf$what  
NULL
```

Comment: It's not inconsistent.  Leading substrings of names are resolved if and only if there is a unique match.

Comment: +1 for making me think about *why* `$` is implemented this way.

Comment: This goes back to the earliest days of S at Bell labs. It is a bad thing, but I still use it sometimes to save typing. Also works in function arguments, For example `predict(m, type = "resp")` or `cor(x, y, use="pair")`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that partial matching by the `$` operator was a nice(r) feature for interactive use back in the days before tabbed completion had been implemented

If you don't like that behavior, you can use the `"[["` operator instead. 
It takes an argument `exact=`, which allows you to control partial matching behavior, and which defaults to `TRUE`.

```
wtf[["whatisthep"]]                 # Only returns exact matches
# NULL

wtf[["whatisthep", exact=FALSE]]    # Returns partial matches without warning
# [1] 2

wtf[["whatisthep", exact=NA]]       # Returns partial matches & warns that it did
# [1] 2
# Warning message:
# In wtf[["whatisthep", exact = NA]] :
#   partial match of 'whatisthep' to 'whatisthepointofthis'
```

(This is one reason why `"[["` is generally preferred to `$` in R programming. Another is the ability to do this `X <- "whatisthe"; wtf[[X]]` but not this `X <- "whatisthe"; wtf$X`.)

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm sure the autocomplete is supposed to be helpful, but it just feels kind of ominous.  I'm just waiting for it to bite again.

Comment: @user1073999 -- I agree. I even feel like I've seen some of the R principals bemoan that early design decision, but can't right now remember where. I'd be interested if anyone else has seen that.

Comment: On further thought, I can see that it would have been helpful in interactive use before tabbed autocompletion had been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

For list element names (and function parameter names), R applies the following algorithm:

If there is an exact match for the item, use it.  If there is not an exact match, look for partial matches.  If there is exactly one partial match, use it.  Otherwise, use nothing.

Comment: I think the complete algorithm also uses positional matching.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  For example '> a <- function(aa,ab) { paste(aa,ab,sep=" ") }' '> a(a=1, a=2)' 'Error in a(a = 1, a = 2) : formal argument "aa" matched by multiple actual arguments'

Comment: I'm simply observing that you don't have to name the argument, in which case R uses positional matching. Since you can mix the case of having argument names and no names, a complete answer should mention this, in my opinion. So, in your example `a(1, ab=2)` will still work, as does `a(ab=2, 1)`.