# R lists -- how are element names handled?

Tags: r, list, syntax

I have noticed this unexpected feature:

```
foo <- list(whatever=1:10)
```

Now, the following works as well:

```
foo$wha
foo$w
foo$whateve
```

However, the following does not:

```
foo[["wha"]]
```

This has the unexpected consequences (unexpected for me, that is) that if you have two potential names, like "[CXCL1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CXCL1)" and "[CXCL11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CXCL11)", and you want to know whether CXCL1 is not null by inspecting `!is.null(foo$CXCL1)`, it will return TRUE even if CXCL1 null, but CXCL11 isn't.

My questions are:

1. How does that work?
2. What is the difference between `foo$whatever` and `foo[["whatever"]]`?
3. Why would anyone want this behavior and how do I disable it?

Comment: [Here's my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066464/you-can-abbreviate-list-names-why/11066583#11066583)

Comment: `help("[[")` is of great value here (it discusses the 'partial matching' you are experiencing). You should consider `foo[["thing", exact=TRUE]]` if you need precision in matching (that's the default for `[[` though). You can also set `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)` to get warnings.

Comment: You might avoid the problem in your case at least by filling up the list with all potential names and set them e.g.  `CXCL1=NULL`

Comment: @hrbrmstr: v. good hint, thank you! Daniel Fischer: nope, this would not work, as assigning NULL removes the element.

Comment: @January Of course, but you could initialize the list maybe with all possible names and then fill it.

Comment: I would stick with [["name"]] anyway. Many R idiosyncrasies are there to save a couple of keystrokes on the command line, but end up causing problems: you should feel lucky you noticed this problem early.

Comment: If you assign not `NULL` but an empty vector, e.g. `integer(0)` you can test for this instead of `NULL`, and prevent the partial matching when names conflict.

Comment: Not really, because for that, I would have to know up front that there is a possibility of CXCL1 existing. What if I wonder "is there a gene called CXCL11111?" (there isn't). For now, I will simply stick with the [[ operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Partial matching only works with unique initial subsequences of list names. So, for example:

   ```
   > l <- list(score=1, scotch=2)
   > l$core #only INITIAL subsequences
   NULL
   > l$sco #only UNIQUE subsequences
   NULL
   > l$scor
   [1] 1
   ```
2. Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list.  The main      differences are that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does, and that partial matching is allowed by default with operator `$` but not with `[[`.
3. These *Extract or Replacement* operators come from S, although R restricts the use of partial matching, while S uses partial matching in most operators by default.

In your example, if `CXCL1` and `CXCL11` coexist and you index `foo$CXCL1`,  that's not a partial match and should return `CXCL1`'s value. If not, maybe there's another problem.

I should point out, `[[` not allowing partial matching as default starts from version `R 2.7.0` onwards.